# Inserting link bug

Tags: support, hyperlinks

When typing in question:

I came across term "half bandgap voltage reference". I expect it is somehow related to ">bandgap circuit. Do you know what it is, know its schematic or principle of operation?

The link is not displayed correctly in the browser (while it is correctly displayed in the preview).

I am using FF 3.6.13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is in reference to your question [What half-bandgap voltage reference is?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9766/what-half-bandgap-voltage-reference-is)

The [first revision](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/01af3c32-8a39-44f8-88dc-fc832ccf3561/view-source) was:

```
I came across term "half bandgap voltage reference". I expect it is somehow
related to [bandgap circuit]
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandgap_voltage_reference>). Do you know what it 
is, know its schematic or principle of operation?
```

Which should work less that trailing `>` in the URL which would be the inline version of [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) linking.  The live preview may have ignored it while the server's parser got confused and gave up.  (The preview and actual results are often very different.  `<sarcasm?>`As best as I can tell, the devs don't care and this will never be fixed as it's been like that for since I've been using SO/SE.`</sarcasm?>`)

Apparently you ultimately used a standard HTML `<a>` tag, which does work along with a [very limited set](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user).

If you use the link tool in a post, which *almost always* works, it uses the reference Markdown link style, doing something like:

```
Lorum ipsum [first revision][1] dolor

...Sic quod veritas...

  [1]: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/01af3c32-8a39-44f8-88dc-
fc832ccf3561/view-source
```

Comment: Thanks for explenation